# Uploading images from website (HTML form) with iOS device (iPad, iPhone)

Tags: ios

I know there are other similar questions out there, but they seem to be at least a few years old.

I was wondering, with the updates to iOS, if it is possible for a user to be able to upload a photo to a website in Safari. If so, how is this done? Through a standard HTML form?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to upload images to server using web api? What do you mean through Standard HTML form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, since iOS 6, you can upload photos from your camera roll using a standard HTML form. You can try it yourself on any site that allows for image uploads, like http://fineuploader.com/demos.html